# Flask python - Import redis from config file

Tags: python, flask, redis, configuration, app-config

I have 2 environment and one of the environment is clusterdisabled, the other is cluster enabled.
To handle this, i added a key in config
For one of the environment it's

```
redis_class = "Redis"
```

The other environment has

```
redis_class = "RedisCluster"
```

init.py

```
 from myapp.config import config
 #this printed the value 
 print(config["redis_class")
 redis_class = config["redis_class"]
 from redis import redis_class as Redis
```

The last line in init.py is throwing an error. How do I import classes from config?

Thanks in advance

Comment: The path is correct, I validated them and we are also able to print redis_class variable in init.py

Comment: and what is the error?

Comment: redis_class not found, cannot import error

Comment: You are misusing the variable names with imports

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try out something like this,

```
redis_class = config["redis_class"]
if redis_class == 'Redis':
    from redis import Redis
else:
    from redis import RedisCluster as Redis
```

or keep the above code in another file(`config.py`) and in your main file you can import it directly.

like `from config import Redis`

---

Without using `if-condition` you can try with `getattr` like this

```
import redis

redis_class = config["redis_class"]
Redis = getattr(redis, redis_class) 

# use the redis class as normal
Redis(...)
```

Comment: Yeah...I tried this but can't we dynamically import without if condition.

Comment: @Codelearner, We can do using `getattr`, updated the answer.

Comment: @Vyshnavi This will import a module but not the class which is callable. I assume you want to import a class from `redis` module?

Answer (score 0):

```
__import__("redis", fromlist=["RedisCluster"])
```

Comment: Avoid code only answer and provide an explanation.